# How to implement IStringLocalizer indexer with async method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-localization

ASP.NET Core 5 MVC application gets translations in from table at runtime. EF Core async methods are used to implement `IStringLocalizer` interface.

The code shown below causes compile-time error:

> The modifier 'async' is not valid for this item

on this line

```
public async LocalizedString this[string name] => new LocalizedString(name, await I(name));
```

How to implement `IStringLocalizer` interface using EF Core async data access?

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

/// <summary>
/// Translation service.
/// Retrieves localized strings from database
/// </summary>
public sealed class Localizer : IStringLocalizer
{
    readonly EevaContext ctx;

    public Localizer(EevaContext ctx)
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    async Task<string> I(string str)
        {   
            return await ctx.Strings
                            .Where((s) => s.Est == estString.)
                            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(); 
        }

    #region interface implementation
    public async LocalizedString this[string name] => new LocalizedString(name, await I(name));
    public LocalizedString this[string name, params object[] arguments] => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer in  [async Indexer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174453/async-indexer-in-c-sharp)  states that indexer can return Task . Maybe this can used.

Comment: Can you make `I` not `async` by using `SingleOrDefault`? Then you can call it synchronously in your property, too.

Comment: Page contains 20-30 different texts which should localized. Sync localizer forces Razor engine to wait sequentially for every string from database. Hopefuly using async localizer renders page much faster if there are lot of requests. Tried to set indexer type to Task<string> and using Run in getter as described in one referenced answer but in this case separate thread is crerated for every call (for some string real application code returns value from memory) and compile time async/await pattern cannot used

Comment: I think the idea is to load all translations in memory before accessing them. Can't you load all your translations at once, instead of reading your database for each string?